# why always only append to last element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code....

```
var BankDescriptions = data.GetResult.map(function(item) {

         var Bank1 = document.getElementById("BTBank1");
         var Bank2 = document.getElementById("BTBank2");
         var Bank3 = document.getElementById("BTBank3");
         var Bankopt = document.createElement('option');
         Bankopt.value = item.BankNo;
         Bankopt.innerHTML = item.BankName;
         Bank1.appendChild(Bankopt);
         BTBank2.appendChild(Bankopt);
         BTBank3.appendChild(Bankopt);
});
```

`data.GetResult` is a Object array, like:

```
[{BankName: "test1", BankNo: "1"},{BankName: "test2", BankNo: "2"}]
```

On my page, only ***BTBank3*** correctly append child, **why?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are passing the same element all the 3 times, so the element is moved from one parent to another one.

You need to pass a new instance each time, you can use the [cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method to create a clone of the object.

Since you need 3 instances, you can clone the object twice and then pass the object to the 3rd call like

```js
var data = {
  GetResult: [{
    BankName: "test1",
    BankNo: "1"
  }, {
    BankName: "test2",
    BankNo: "2"
  }]
}

var Bank1 = document.getElementById("BTBank1");
var Bank2 = document.getElementById("BTBank2");
var Bank3 = document.getElementById("BTBank3");
var BankDescriptions = data.GetResult.forEach(function(item) {
  var Bankopt = new Option(item.BankName, item.BankNo);
  Bank1.appendChild(Bankopt.cloneNode(true));
  Bank2.appendChild(Bankopt.cloneNode(true));
  Bank3.appendChild(Bankopt);
});
```

```html
<select id="BTBank1"></select>
<select id="BTBank2"></select>
<select id="BTBank3"></select>
```

Comment: Why your answer works if there is no var `BTBank2, BTBank3`? Looks strange to me.

Comment: @Jai Accidentally, his code used the named access. Elements with id can be reference in global scope with same id.

Comment: @Jai since the elements has ID, those are available as properties of the window object

Comment: @ArunPJohny Frankly speaking i didn't think of it.

Comment: @ArunPJohny so, in that case why use `getElementById()` then. can't just that way it could be used? just curious to know if there are some gotchas.

Comment: @Jai if in a parent scope somebody else created a variable with the same name then we are in trouble other than that nothing

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks! got it now.